# How to change the email address where SQL Server sends log shipping warnings to?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, log-shipping

Years ago, I set up log shipping in our main database.
I'm sure that I had to enter my email address somewhere, because every time when something bad happens now (for example, when the secondary database is not in sync), SQL Server sends warning emails to me.

Now, I would like to change this address (someone else will have to deal with the warnings from now on).
But how/where can I do this?

I looked at the log shipping settings of the primary database in Management Studio, and I let Management Studio generate a script with the log shipping settings and looked at that, but I can neither see the current address anywhere, nor a place where I can enter a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the SQL Server Agent|Alerts|Pick the alert you want to edit |Response|Add the Operator

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you! I never noticed that there are alerts shown under the SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)